# Issues with Looping

Tags: java, loops

I am very new to Java. So I've created a script to receive input of a score, and then give a mark as output based on this score. My issue is I want the code to repeat to allow for entry of multiple scores, but I can't get it to work.

Edit: I have tried using the methods in the answers but I can't get it right. would it be possible for someone to do implement the loop into my code for me?
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class week4
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        {

    String studentname;
    int mark = 100;   // listing maximum mark
    Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the student >> ");
    studentname = inText.nextLine();
    Scanner inNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter mark for student " + studentname + " out of 100 >> ");
    mark = inText.nextInt();
    if(mark <50) System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is F " );
    else if(mark <65) System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is P " );
    else if(mark <75) System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is C " );
    else if(mark <85) System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is D " );
    else System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is HD2" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wrap you code within a for loop with the number of times you need it to loop eg `for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){ }` for a looping 10 times..add the loop  above the scanner inputs i.e above `Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: you can use `while` loop for your goal. look some while loop docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's refactor the main logic into another method called calcGrade():

```
public void calcGrade() {

    String studentname;
    int mark = 100;   // listing maximum mark
    Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the student >> ");
    studentname = inText.nextLine();
    Scanner inNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter mark for student " + studentname + " out of 100 >> ");
    mark = inText.nextInt();
    if(mark <50) System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is F " );
    else if(mark <65) System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is P " );
    else if(mark <75) System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is C " );
    else if(mark <85) System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is D " );
    else System.out.print("The grade for " + studentname + " is HD2" );
}
```

If we invoke this method, it will load a new student name & score from System.in, calculate the grade then print it.

Okay, the next part will be the loop.

There are 3 types of loop in Java, for/while/do-while.

You can use "for" when you know exactly what times you want to loop.

E.g. You know there is only 10 students in your class, then you can write such codes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    calcGrade();
}
```

If you don't know the times, but you know there is an exact condition to end the loop, you can use while or do-while. The difference between while and do-while is while can do the condition check first then do the inner logic, and do-while always do the inner logic for once time then check the condition.

E.g. You want to continue the loop when you acquire a String "YES" from the System.in.

```
System.out.println("Please input the first student info, YES or NO?");
Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);
while ("YES".equals(inText.nextLine()) {
    calcGrade();
    System.out.println("Continue input the next student info, YES or NO?");
}
```

Also, you can use the do-while, if you know there are at least one people in the class.

```
Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    calcGrade();
    System.out.println("Continue input the next student info, YES or NO?");
} while ("YES".equals(inText.nextLine());
```

Hopes it's clear for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest wway I can think of is to create a class called student and have variables for name, subjects, scores etc. Have setters and getters if you want or just have a constructor which takes in those inputs. Next have a method like computeGrade(). Creates instances of this student class every time you want some thing.

```
puclic class Student{

public String mName;
public String mSub1;
.
public int m_scoreSub1;
.
.
public computeScore(int m_score){
* your logic goes here ( the if else one)
}
}
```

Now just instantiate the class !!!